# How do I calculate WPF all camera setting dynamically in the code?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have Viewport3D in the Window.  it will change the size when the window size changed.

```
<Window>
  <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
      <RowDefinition/>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Label Grid.Row="0" Content="top label"/>
    <Viewport3D Grid.Row="1" x:Name="vp3D" >
            <Viewport3D.Camera >
                 <PerspectiveCamera x:Name="pCamera"  LookDirection="0 0 -1" UpDirection="0 1 0" />
            </Viewport3D.Camera>
            <Viewport2DVisual3D x:Name="v2dv3d">
                  <Viewport2DVisual3D.Geometry>
                      <MeshGeometry3D x:Name="mg3d" TextureCoordinates="0,0 0,1 1,1 1,0" TriangleIndices="0 1 2 0 2 3"/>
                   </Viewport2DVisual3D.Geometry>
                   <Viewport2DVisual3D.Material>
                         <DiffuseMaterial Viewport2DVisual3D.IsVisualHostMaterial="True" Brush="White"/>
                   </Viewport2DVisual3D.Material>

                          <Image  Height="{Binding ElementName=vp3D, Path=ActualHeight}" Width="{Binding ElementName=vp3D, Path=ActualWidth}" Stretch="Fill"/>

            </Viewport2DVisual3D>
            <ModelVisual3D>
                 <ModelVisual3D.Content>
                      <DirectionalLight Color="#FFFFFFFF" Direction="0,0,-1"/>
                 </ModelVisual3D.Content>
           </ModelVisual3D>
  </Viewport3D>
 </Grid>
</Window
```

Now **I want the image show on like it's the original 2d window(look like nothing changed, but actually the image is 3d).**

But problem is If I want it looking same as the same as WPF original look at, I must change some Camera settings, like `PerspectiveCamera.Position` or `MeshGeometry3D.Position`. because the `Viewport3D` will change the size dynamically when the window change size, I must dynamically calculate the `Viewport3D` settings.  Is there anyway to do ?

I've already tried this, but can't calculate correctly: 
[WPF 3D: Fitting entire image to view with PerspectiveCamera](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17382853/wpf-3d-fitting-entire-image-to-view-with-perspectivecamera)

Comment: I tried my best and read your question twice, but I still don't understand it. Are you trying to have that image like a background behind the Viewport?

Comment: @MarkusHütter Basically I want that `Image` show on like there is no `Viewport3D`. only a `Label` and `Image` in the `Grid`, and the `Grid` could change the size by the `Window`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finish it by myself.

```
// get the Viewport3D size first, If you want to use .ActualWidth or .ActualHeight property get it, make sure your application loaded finish, otherwise it will return 0.
double height = ; // get the Viewport3D height or calculate the height first
double width = ; //  get the Viewport3D width or calculate the width first


mg3d.Positions.Clear();
mg3d.Positions.Add(new Point3D(-width, height, 0.0));
mg3d.Positions.Add(new Point3D(-width, -height, 0.0));
mg3d.Positions.Add(new Point3D(width, -height, 0.0));
mg3d.Positions.Add(new Point3D(width, height, 0.0));


double fieldOfViewInRadians = pCamera.FieldOfView * (Math.PI / 180.0);
var z = (width) / Math.Tan(0.5 * fieldOfViewInRadians);
pCamera.Position = new Point3D(0.0, 0.0, z);
```

You also need to make sure calculate it again if your window size changed. After that, you could do any 3d animation which you want.

Comment: I have the same problem as you. Thanks for the answer. In addition, I would like to ask where you found solutions or related information. Because the problem I'm facing now is how to solve the angle problem in Viewport 2DVisual3D.

Comment: @GoldliZh, Hi, As you see I put a address in my question at the end, but it not calculate correctly, so I can only try more hard to search, or trying to change it and suitable to my scenario. I'm sorry I'm not a 3D expert to help you. I can only advice you: put your're question on stackoverflow.

Comment: @GoldliZh, Also I must warn you: 3D will cause too much performance problems. I also advice you use the 3D only when you trying to play a animation, such like: get a screenshot of you window, hide the window, and show 3D play a animation with the screenshot image, hide 3D image and resume to the real window. otherwise it will take too much resource, you still need to cost too much performance.

Comment: Thank you very much, first of all. In fact i use 3D for animation. I had trying to use normal 2D transform , but it seems not transform smoothly , so i have to change it to 3D. And i'm an beginner of 3D too.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure if that is what you want, but have you tried this?

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
      <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Label Grid.Row="0" Content="top label"/>
    <Image HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="1" Stretch="Fill"/>
    <Viewport3D Grid.Row="1" x:Name="vp3D">
            <Viewport3D.Camera >
                 <PerspectiveCamera x:Name="pCamera" Position="0,0,1" LookDirection="0,0,-1" />
            </Viewport3D.Camera>
            <Viewport2DVisual3D x:Name="v2dv3d">
                  <Viewport2DVisual3D.Geometry>
                      <MeshGeometry3D x:Name="mg3d" Positions="-1,1,0 -1,-1,0 1,-1,0 1,1,0" TextureCoordinates="0,0 0,1 1,1 1,0" TriangleIndices="0 1 2 0 2 3"/>
                   </Viewport2DVisual3D.Geometry>
                   <Viewport2DVisual3D.Material>
                         <DiffuseMaterial Viewport2DVisual3D.IsVisualHostMaterial="True" Brush="White"/>
                   </Viewport2DVisual3D.Material>
            </Viewport2DVisual3D>
            <ModelVisual3D>
                 <ModelVisual3D.Content>
                      <DirectionalLight Color="#FFFFFFFF" Direction="0,0,-1"/>
                 </ModelVisual3D.Content>
           </ModelVisual3D>
      </Viewport3D>
</Grid>
```

Comment: I'm sorry,  I need the `Image` in the `Viewport3D`. Because I need show some 3d animation later. thank you.

Comment: have you tried my code? The Image should be exactly behind the `Viewport3D` so you still can show your 3D stuff in front of it. If that's not what you want to do I urge you to improve your question!

Comment: no need to get offended, buddy. I'll keep this post up though, so people like me, that are trying to help you and don't quite get _what_ you want will at least know what you _don't want_.

Comment: please delete your answer, I've already done it by myself. I don't understand why some people even vote this after I explain it so much clear.